# Spring type second order derivatives question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've started revising for exams and have begun going through a set of practice questions and came upon a question that I have no idea how it works within the topic stated. Just wondering if someone could show me how they go about solving it.

A block of wood of width d = 0.18m, length l = 0.2m, height h = 1m and weight m = 27kg floats with its axis vertical in some liquid of density ρ kg/m3. The equilibrium position corresponds to the centre of mass being 0.3m below the surface of the liquid. Initially, the block is at its equilibrium position with a downward velocity of v0 = 0.5m/s. At the same time an external force G(t) = k cos(ωt) Newton is applied to the block. Let x(t) denote the location
of the centre of mass of the block from its equilibrium position with x(t) > 0 corresponding to below the equilibrium position. The resistance and the kinetic energy of the liquid are both neglected and the acceleration due to gravity is 9.8m/s2. Assume that the block never leaves or sinks in the liquid completely.

(a) Calculate the value of ρ, the density of the liquid.

(b) Apply Newton’s law of motion on the vertical axis to prove that x(t) is described by the differential equation
       x¨ + 12.25x =kcos(ωt)/27

c) Solve for x(t) for all ω

(d) Let k = 5. Will ω = 2 or ω = 3.5 satisfy the assumption that the block never leaves or sinks in the liquid?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

First find the natural frequency $\omega$ of the vertically floating spring as a function of immersion depth.. [height h of floating body](http://silverbullet.in/chapters/lessonsummary/1748/1705) Then treat it as a conventional mechanical spring with corresponding stiffness and oscillating mass.

Comment: any other tips cause im still sort of lost